# Issue in traversing XML node in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an issue of iterating xml in java .I have a root node as element,inside element tag two sub nodes are there, but i am getting node length as 1. can any one guide me how to rectify it. I have mentioned my code below.

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;


public class Test {




        public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception{


             String xmlRecords = "<data><employee><name>A</name><title>Manager</title><name>B</name><title>Manager</title></employee></data>";

            DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

            Document doc = db.parse(is);

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
              Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

              NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
              Element line = (Element) name.item(i);
              System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

              NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
              line = (Element) title.item(i);
              System.out.println("Title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
            }

          }

          public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
            Node child = e.getFirstChild();
            if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
              CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
              return cd.getData();
            }
            return "";
          }

}
```

**Result:**

```
Name: A
Title: Manager
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  Name: A
    Title: Manager
    Name: B
    Title: Manager
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is

```
<data>
   <employee>
      <name>A</name>
      <title>Manager</title>
      <name>B</name>
      <title>Manager</title>
   </employee>
</data>
```

I would suggest you try it with

```
<data>
   <employee>
      <name>A</name>
      <title>Manager</title>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <name>B</name>
      <title>Manager</title>
   </employee>
</data>
```

There is otherwise (correctly) only 1 employee node of which you print a name and title

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things: there is only one `<employee>` node, so your loop iterates once. Consider adding a second node to String:

```
String xmlRecords = "<data><employee><name>A</name><title>Manager</title></employee>" +
                    "<employee><name>B</name><title>Manager</title></employee></data>";
```

Secondly, for the `<name>` and `<title>` do not iterate on these inner nodes as there is only one within each employee. So use zeros instead of the `i`. This of course depends on above parent node change.

```
NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
Element line = (Element) name.item(0);

NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
line = (Element) title.item(0);
```

Doing above yields your desired result:

```
Name: A
Title: Manager
Name: B
Title: Manager
```